# getting indentation error when trying to print in intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have this Indentation error in IntelliJ, I can print without the tab, but as soon as I use the tab it I get this error. I have been looking all over and tried what to change the detecting box and smart tabs but nothing seems to work.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUWiq.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JuSx.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTOpn.jpg

Comment: Post all code and errors in text format, not as images. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace is syntactically important to the python interpreter. You can't do what you are trying to do, it is a syntax error.